# multiple @OneToMany @ManyToOne bidirectional relationships in one class

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm getting infinite error when selecting from a class that has multiple @OneToMany relationship, and i need your help with my mapping.

in fact i get orders with associated company and associated lineItems including products, so the JSON response is too long to show all the result.

I'v tried fetchType.EAGER and removing cascade at all but it doesn't seem to work.

**Infinite Error**

```
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:727) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.5.jar:2.9.5]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:719) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.5.jar:2.9.5]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.5.jar:2.9.5]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:145) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.5.jar:2.9.5]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:107) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.5.jar:2.9.5]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:25) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.5.jar:2.9.5]
```

**Mapping**

```
@Entity
public class Contact implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_company")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Company company;

}

@Entity
public class Company implements Serializable{

    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)   
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<Contact> contacts = new HashSet<Contact>();
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<Order> orders = new HashSet<Order>();

}



@Entity
public class Order implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_order")
    private Set<LineItem> lineItems= new HashSet<LineItem>();
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_company")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Company company;

}

@Entity
public class LineItem implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_product")
    private Product product;    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_order")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Order order; 
}

@Entity
public class Product implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)   
}
```

How can i fix that in my mapping and show all orders with associated Company, all companies, and all lineItems with associated Order and associated Product?

Comment: Can you add your Product class, code which calls your entities and full stacktrace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the relation among the entities form loop, Spring serializer will have problem to generate json.
Try to introduce `@JsonIgnore` on some fields to stop the loop.